# Use a JMenu as a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jmenu

I have a JMenuBar containing some JMenu items that do not have a submenu, rather they just turn a feature on or off.  I accomplish this by detecting a mouse click.

For convenience, I tried to add an accelerator for this function but when I use the accelerator, the menu is selected but no action occurs.

Is there a way that a JMenu can be configured to act as a button both when it is clicked and triggered by an accelerator?

Comment: Yes.  JMenuItem is a subclass of AbstractButton, so you'd have to extend JMenuItem and implement the ActionListener.  Here's an example http://www.herongyang.com/Swing/JMenuBar-Menu-Item-Action-Listener-Test.html

Comment: Would you consider using a [JToolBar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) instead of a `JMenu`?